# Constrain mouse movement on Mac, similar to Windows ClipCursor?

Tags: cocoa, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I lock the cursor to the inside of a window on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642863/how-can-i-lock-the-cursor-to-the-inside-of-a-window-on-mac-os-x)

On Mac, is there an API that can confine a cursor to a rectangular region? E.g. on Windows there is [ClipCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); on Linux [XGrabPointer](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabPointer.html).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is definitely not normal behaviour on Mac OS X.

Comment: Plenty of reasons. What if you authored a game that supported windowed mode?